# Handling European Number Formats in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this input field Where I expect the user to enter a float value, beieng a amount.
The actual behavior is, that if the input is **12.00** it will be accepted.
But if the User enters **12** it will be rejected.

```
<input id="f1" type="text" placeholder="00,00" type="text" name="f1" pattern="([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})">
```

What I desire is that if the user enters 12 or 12.00 it should be formatted 12,00 because this is what we use in Europe. And if the user enters 12.23 it should be formatted instantly 12,23.
But it should only be shown this way. The value should be 12.23 not 12230.

I could use **str.replace** but then I have a string and not a float. So each time I read the field I must replace it back and turn it into a float.

Now the big question ist there a more elegant way to handle this ?

Comment: have you tried this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: **In Firefox** you just have to set the `lang` of your document and they will *render* it as expected while keeping the value usable for JS: https://jsfiddle.net/ot6d1L0n/ Too bad they're the only ones doing that...

Comment: @Kaiido very interesting, seems like I can place the lang="de" also in the input tag :))

Comment: @Kaiido I tested Edge, it is also working.